# Calculating Consistency of Ranking

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, survey, normality-assumption

I am trying to calculate an overall index that provides a quick indication of how consistent the person was in the ranking of their responses in a forced-choice format (i.e. Ipsative) questionnaire.

Let's say for example, I am asking the person their preference of different kinds of fruit (e.g. apple, orange, banana etc.). In one question, I will present six options to the respondent: (Fruit list is presented not in order of preference)

Question Set A:

1. Orange
2. Apple
3. Strawberry
4. Blueberry
5. Banana
6. Pear

In this question, the person is then to rank them from 'MOST' to 'LEAST' preferred fruit. Let's say this is his response: (6 being most preferred, 1 being least preferred)

Response to Question Set A:

6 Blueberry
5 Strawberry
4 Apple
3 Pear
2 Banana
1 Orange

The person would have similar sort of questions several times, each time asking a different combination of fruit. But each fruit would have been compared with another set of fruits. So for example, the next question could ask him the following: (Again, not ordered in preference)

Question Set B:

1. Starfruit
2. Durian
3. Apple*
4. Grapes
5. Beets
6. Watermelon

Notice now we asked Apple again, but it's being compared to a different set of fruits. Now let's say this is his response: (In order of preference)

Response to Question Set B:

6 Beets
5 Durian
4 Apple
3 Grapes
2 Watermelon
1 Starfruit

Notice that Apple was again rated the 4th most preferred, similar to the first question. If we asked this several times, and the person ranked Apple in a similar preference, then we would say he was overall very consistent with his preference for Apple.

Now, imagine we are comparing the preference of 30 different fruits. And so, even if we would know the preference level of each fruit relative to each other through this exercise, I want to provide an overall indicator score (i.e. only one score) that represents how consistent the person was when ranking his responses to the fruits.

My initial thought its that I will take the preference score of each fruit, take its Standard Deviation (which will give its variation of scores for the construct of 'Apple), average all the Standard Deviations for each of the 30 fruits, and then standardize the score based on a norm group to get an overall index. My issue is that is calculating the average of a Standard Deviation of scores to use as an index be appropriate?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think this form of ranking 'consistency' would be meaningful? Variation in the ranks of one item depend upon the other items in the set. Taking an extreme example, it's perfectly possible for an individual to love the fruits in the first set, hate those in the second set, and be indifferent to apples, such that apple is ranked last in Set A, and first in Set B. This wouldn't be inconsistent at all, even though the SD would be inflated. Have you considered a [paired comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_comparison) approach?

Comment: @awhug you are definitely right about the possibility of the individual loving the fruit in the first set, but might hate it in the second set as ranked comparisons are interdependent with each other due to the nature of the task. I have not considered paired comparisons, but I'll definitely take a look. I'm just wondering if there is a simple way to indicate how consistent the person was in their ranking of fruits? I still plan on standardising their level of consistency to a norm group, which will help provide context.

Comment: Rather than thinking about ranks as *absolute* values, it might be helpful to consider them as *relative*. For instance, if you're repeating fruits across sets, you might be able to consider consistency in terms of transitivity. Ranking apple > banana and banana > pear in one set implies apple > pear, but this might be violated by an individual in a different set. Counting the instances of intransitivity like this could get you something like the [coefficient of consistence](http://doi.org/10.2307/2332613) (Kendall & Babbington Smith, 1940). How this applies to ranks though I'm not sure.